# CakePHP default validation not working in IE

Tags: cakephp

The below code is creating input box with label and **'required'=>'required'** is mandatory field. This is not working in IE.

```
<?php $this->Form->input('name', array('type'=>'text','placeholder'=>__('name'),'required' => 'required'));?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: 'required'=>true? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#required

Comment: You need to be more specific. A) what is the html output? B) in what exact IE version isnt it working? IE is know to provide certain features (like HTML5 in this case) as the latest of all.

Comment: 1.This is the HTML output<input name="data[Users][name]" class="txtboxbg" type="text" placeholder="Name" required="1"/>
2. Windows7 IE8.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any input with `required="required"` is to prevent submitting the form if the input is empty with a hint of `Please fill in this field` (or similar). This is one of the many features introduced in [html5 capable browsers](http://john.foliot.ca/required-inputs/).

Set `'required' => 'false'` on your input fields and you will notice that cakephp's validation will take over, assuming you have your validation rules in the Model offcourse

```
<?php $this->Form->input('name', array('type'=>'text','placeholder'=>__('name'),'required' => 'false'));?>
```